# Can emitting an event after a state change cause a reentrancy attack vulnerability?

Tags: solidity, security, reentrant-attacks

Is the following function vulnerable to a reentrancy attack?

```
function withdraw() public {
     uint amount = pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender];
     // Remember to zero the pending refund before
     // sending to prevent re-entrancy attacks
     pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender] = 0;
     msg.sender.transfer(amount);
     emit AmountWithdrawn(msg.sender, amount);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not vulnerable to a reentrancy attack. An event will not cause a function to throw.

The way you have it written is very secure, in that you are updating `pendingWithdrawals` prior to the sending of the `amount`.

In the future, try to keep the structure of all the functions you write very similar to this, in that you change the state prior to performing actions.